# laravel 5 - get related model values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models, mission and projects.
In both of the models there is a belongsToMany function (n:m)
When I select all the missions, I will eager load all the projects too:

```
$missions = Mission::with('projects')->get();
```

Now I want all the related projects from each mission but as a distinct result.

I mean if I have 3 missions and all the missions belongs to ONE project I want this project name in an array.

But if mission 1 belongs to project 1 and mission 2 belongs to project 2, I want get an array of names of project 1 and 2.

But how can I do this?
I try this but have no luck:

```
$array = $missions->toArray();
$projectNames = array_pluck($array, 'projects.name');
```

Also I try this:

```
$missionIDs = $missions->pluck('id');
```

give me all ID's of the missions .. but I try to get the related project names (belongsToMany) so I try this too:

```
$projects = $missions->pluck('projects')->unique();
```

gives me the projects .. but not unique.. it's weird.
And this does not work, I get an empty collection if I try to select only the projectnames:

```
$projectNames = $missions->pluck('projects.names')->unique());
```

I think the problem is the n:m relation between project and missions but I am not sure.

> EDIT Finally I got it:

```
$projectNames = $missions->pluck('projects.*.name')->unique();
```

The trick is to use the * because it is belongsToMany ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$projectNames = $missions->lists('projects.name')->unique();
```

This will return a Collection object.

Comment: I only get an empty collection if I use your code after my $missions = Mission::with('projects')->get(); :

Collection {#488
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => null
  ]
}

Comment: The whole relevant code is this: $missions = Mission::with('projects')->get();
It gives me a result over many missions, with the related projects in "projects". And I want only the unique projectnames of all missions... I try it with ->pluck('projects.name')->unique(); but I get only an empty collection. with ->pluck('projects'); I get the projects, but not unique, and not only the projectnames.

Comment: This is most probably the result of some typo (in column or table name). So check `'projects.name'`

Comment: nope .. I got it. See in my question. Thank you nevertheless.